# How can I get the line.column index for the right-click event on Tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

Say - I am working on a tk.Text widget with the following content:

```
this is a test text.
which has two lines.
```

Say I right-click on the beginning of the first "h" in the first word "which" in the second line - and I want to access its location in the tk.Text's line.column format just as follows:

```
rc_index = tk.Text.get_right_click_index('current') 
print(rc_index)
```

The output shall be:

```
2.1
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assume `text` is the instance of the `Text` widget, then you can bind `"<Button-3>"` (right click event of mouse in Windows) to a callback and get the index inside the callback:

```py
def on_right_click(event):
    idx = event.widget.index("current")
    print(idx)

text.bind("<Button-3>", on_right_click)
```